# C++, Simple Function, Unreasonable Error?

Tags: c++, debugging

So I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "secondary.h"
using namespace std;

void printNumber(int x = 1, float z = 1.01);

int main(){
    int a = 54;
    float b = 39.1243;

    printNumber(a);
}

void printNumber(int x, float z){
    cout << x, z << endl;
}
```

Since I already set the default of float z to 1.01, there can't be an error if I don't enter the two parameters. However instead, it's giving me this error:

> error: invalid operands of types 'float' and '' to binary 'operator<<'

Comment: if you replace the comma between the x and the y in the printNumber implementation with << it should compile better...

Comment: Why are people down voting my question? If you're going to do that have the decency to tell me why/write a response.

Comment: Have a  look at operator precedence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: One reason may be the unhelpful title which gives no indication of what your question is about.

Comment: Another reason may be that your title calls the error unreasonable, but anybody looking at your code will tell you that the mistake is relatively basic. Not the one downvoting, but I am going to vote to close this question because I don't think this is an error that people commonly make.

Comment: Since when is "not a common error" a reason to close?

Comment: The downvotes are likely for various reasons like you're not actually asking a question and the description of the problem could use a bit of polish. Your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is concise and allows the problem to be easily solved. Even though you've got two answers which will help solve your problem I still suggest polishing up your post a bit, at the very least it'll help next time you need to post on SO.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "secondary.h"
using namespace std;

void printNumber(int x = 1, float z = 1.01);

int main(){
    int a = 54;
    float b = 39.1243;

    printNumber(a);
}

void printNumber(int x, float z){
    cout << x << z << endl;
    cout << x << "," << z << endl; //alternative
}
```

change `,` to `<<`

Answer (score 1):

CyberGuy already (instantly) provided the solution, I'll add an explanation on how [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and comma operator (with lowest priority) plays the role here.

This is the affected line:

```
cout << x, z << endl;
```

The next line is equivalent and emphasizes operator precedence:

```
(cout << x), (z << endl);
```

If you want to go further, you can remove the comma operator and split the statement:

```
cout << x; // valid (although no flush)
z << endl; // invalid code
```

`std::endl` is a [stream manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), which is in fact a function and `std::basic_ostream` defines 9th member [`operator<<`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) overload for them. There's no such `operator<<` that accepts `float` and

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &endl(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits> &os);
```

- the declaration of `std::endl`.